# Intel X5650 vs E5-2630

Tags: central-processing-unit

I'm testing two CPUs with `sysbench` - any idea why 'X5650' is faster on a single thread test, 'E5-2630' has a lower clock speed but it's a newer architecture:

```
X5650 2.67GHz: Single thread - 23.6984s; 64-threads - 1.6941s
E5-2630 2.30GHz: Single thread - 30.3731s; 64-threads - 1.6203s
```

'E5-2630' it's running on HP ProLiant Gen8 so I wonder if there is any option to tune CPU permanence?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

On paper you're right, the single-threaded gap shouldn't be so wide, I can only imagine that the BIOS and CPU timings/settings etc. for the older CPU is more well developed than the newer machine. Presumably you're on the latest for the 380?

That said the multi-threading gap is much more realistic. Interesting question btw :)